# RISC V | Read C program identifiers from a RISC-V program [PROBLEM COLLEGE]

Tags: c, replace, uniqueidentifier, identifier, riscv

The statement is this one:

-Write a program in RISC-V assembly using RARS. The program should not rely on uninitialized register
values. The program should not contain any obviously inefficient actions. Do NOT use multiply/divide
instructions for multiplication division by constants being powers of 2. Avoid the sequences of consecutive
branches, esp. conditional branches followed by unconditional ones (unless necessary).
All the text processing programs with file i/o should define getc and putc functions for single-character i/o,
providing proper buffering of input and input operations with at least 512-byte buffers.

- Collect all the identifiers from a valid C program and determine the minimum number of characters
  required to preserve their uniqueness. Produce the replacement list and display it. Assume that the
  minimum length of a modified identifier is equal to or greater than the maximum length of a C
  language keyword.

I am very new in RISC V so **I don't really know how could I get the identifiers of a C language program (.c) from a RISCV program.** Thank you very much!

Comment: Write it in C first.  Then translate the result.

Comment: If you really want to make it complicated, then try doing it in assembly from scratch before you know assembly.  Otherwise, write it in C first, test it to make sure it works, then take that to assembly knowing the algorithm you have already works.